# Extracting words from multiple strings in r

Tags: r, string, text

I have the following string as an example in one column in my data frame:

```
 A = [{'name': 'Bank', 'id': 559}, {'name': 'Cinema', 'id': 2550}, {'name': 'Shopping', 'id': 10201}]
```

I have tried the following code to extract words ('Bank','Cinema','Shopping') from this string but is giving me 'character(0)':

```
 stringr::str_extract_all(A, "\\w+(?='\\})")
```

May I ask how can do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that is straight JSON, you can do something like this:

```
library(jsonlite)

A <- "[{'name': 'Bank', 'id': 559}, {'name': 'Cinema', 'id': 2550}, {'name': 'Shopping', 'id': 10201}]"
A <- gsub("'", '"', A) # fromJSON expects double quotes.

l <- fromJSON(A)
l$name
```

EDIT: Assuming you have a column with multiple JSON arrays like A and not just one JSON array as you showed above in your question, you will need to do something like this:

```
df <- data_frame(A = rep("[{'name': 'Bank', 'id': 559}, {'name': 'Cinema', 'id': 2550}, {'name': 'Shopping', 'id': 10201}]", 5))

df$A <- gsub("'", '"', df$A)
lapply(df$A, function(x) {j <- fromJSON(x); j$name})
```

I just repeated the same JSON array string you provided five times to create a 5-row data frame. Then, use `lapply` on each 'row' to get results from it.

Comment: When I want to do it for every row within that column, I am getting this error: "Error: parse error: trailing garbage". Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post an example data frame with that column and different values?

Answer (score 0):

Hackish (use a `JSON` approach!):

```
A <- c("[{'name': 'Bank', 'id': 559}, {'name': 'Cinema', 'id': 2550}, {'name': 'Shopping', 'id': 10201}]")

pattern <- "'name':\\s*['\"]\\K\\w+"
m <- gregexpr(pattern, A, perl = T)
(words <- unlist(regmatches(A, m)))
```

This will yield

```
[1] "Bank"     "Cinema"   "Shopping"
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for all rows within that column of df?

Comment: @user36729: It is possible though not advisable. Post some more content to see what one can do.